# Register for navigation intent in iOS swift

Tags: google-maps, swift4, deep-linking, url-scheme, ios-app-extension

i have an esri based mapping app which is capable of routing and navigation.

i need to make the system know that my app is capable of routing and navigation when a third party app sends a navigation request and it should list my application among the installed maps app to the user

here is my scenario :

lets say my app is "App A" and a third party app is "App B".

App B has a button when tapped performs navigation,before opening navigation request it launches a selection window in which the system lists the maps app installed in the phone.so the user choose any one.

i need the system to add my app App A to the selection list.

i was able to use intent filters in android to achieve this easily.

what i tried in swift :

1)created a url scheme for comgooglemaps

2)system shows google maps in the app selection window for App B (even though phone doesnt have google maps installed) but opens my app and executes my task as needed

3)if google maps is installed,system opens google maps and my app doesnt receive the callback..

how do i achieve this in swift..

I need my app to be listed here among these Apple and Google maps and handle the request

[image]

please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which is not possible in iOS as of now

AFAIK and from the information gathered from other devs you cant let yourself list app among other apps

The only possible way is to create a URL scheme in my app and let the developer of the third party app to talk to my app using the scheme.